# Measuring Momentum Between Change in Net Positions

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, change-of-variable

Suppose you have 2 numbers labeled "Net Positions" within a time series:

01/08/2005 - A)68923

01/15/2005 - B)80164

The change between A and B would be: 11241 [80164-68923].

Would it be correct to state the velocity between A and B as:

1605.85714 [11241/7 Days Elapsed]?

[Velocity = change in displacement/change in time]

And thus conclude the momentum between A and B as:

128731932 [80164*1605.85714]?

[Momentum = Mass*Velocity (using the current net position as mass)]

Comment: Yes, with the understanding that the velocity you computed is an average velocity over those seven days.

Comment: Thanks..and would it be ok to state the instantaneous rate of change between A and B as: 16.3090..%, or would this simply be the percent change instead?

Comment: Nope. You absolutely cannot say anything about instantaneous velocity. It is not customary to write velocity as a percentage; why would you want to?